# Как реализовать программу, которая принимает последовательность чисел и выводит их сумму на Python?

Tags: python, счетчики

Реализуйте программу, которая принимает последовательность чисел и выводит их сумму.

Вашей программе на вход подается последовательность строк.
Первая строка содержит число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100).
В следующих n строках содержится по одному целому числу.

Выведите одно число – сумму данных n чисел.

```
    print('enter your sign')
n = int(input())
for n in range(1,101):
    if 1 <= n <= 100:
        print(n,n+n)
    else:
        print('your conclusion is wrong!')

Почему не работает, вроде всё правильно?
```

Счётчик чисел есть и суммирует же

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен, не могли бы вы его уточнить? Кстати говоря, это чем-то напоминает последовательность Фибоначчи. Если речь идёт о ней, то алгоритм должен быть слегка другой.
`print(n, n+n)` не сохраняет никаких новых значений в переменной `n`

Comment: https://stepik.org/lesson/24456/step/9?unit=6762 
Честно говоря, я сам не понимаю, что хочет от меня автор курса

Answer (score 1):

Вам наверно нужно что-то такое:

```
n = int(input('Enter number of lines: '))
if (1 <= n and n <= 100):
    sum = 0
    for _ in range(0, n):
        sum += int(input('Enter your sign: '))
        
    print('Sum =', sum)
else:
    print('Your conclusion is wrong!')
```

или

```
n = int(input('Enter number of lines: '))
if (1 <= n and n <= 100):
    sum = 0
    for v in range(1, n+1):
        sum += v
        
    print('Sum =', sum)
else:
    print('Your conclusion is wrong!')
```

или

```
from random import *

n = int(input('Enter number of lines: '))
if (1 <= n and n <= 100):
    sum = 0
    for _ in range(1, n+1):
        sum += randrange(1, 101) 
        
    print('Sum =', sum)
else:
    print('Your conclusion is wrong!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Кажется я понял что от вас хотят.

Вот первый вариант, в котором мы сначала записываем последовательность, а потом считаем сумму:

```
# Просим ввести количество чисел в последовательности
n = int(input('Введите количество чисел в последовательности: '))

# Создаем list, в котором будут храниться инпуты
numbers = []

# Заполняем список числами, которые вводит пользователь
for i in range(0, n):
    input_value = int(input(f'Введите число #{i}: '))
    numbers.append(input_value)

# Считаем сумму
sum = 0
for i in numbers:
    sum += i

print('Сумма всех чисел последовательности:', sum)
```

Есть ещё второй вариант, тут мы сразу же считаем сумму, без сохранения введенных чисел:

```
# Просим ввести количество чисел в последовательности
n = int(input('Введите количество чисел в последовательности: '))

# Сразу же считаем сумму
sum = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    # Запрашиваем число
    input_value = int(input(f'Введите число #{i}: '))
    # Сразу же прибавляем его к сумме
    sum += input_value

print('Сумма всех чисел последовательности:', sum)
```

Оба варианта работают, выбор за вами. Чтобы полностью соответствовать примерам на вашем курсе - можете убрать сообщения, которые внутри `input()`.

Если ещё остались вопросы - пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```py
n = int(input("How many numbers? "))
res = sum(int(input()) for _ in range(n))
print(res)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/index.html